# Gtk - draw event fired for wrong widget, and widget not redrawn

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm trying to create a custom scrollable text area. I created a `DrawingArea` and a `ScrollBar` inside a `Grid`. I have attached the `draw` event of `DrawingArea` to `this.on_draw` method which simply looks at `ScrollBar`'s value and moves the `Cairo.Context` appropriately before drawing the `Pango.Layout`.

The first problem is that `this.on_draw` is getting invoked whenever the `ScrollBar` is touched even though I have not registered any events with `ScrollBar`. How do I prevent this, or check this?

The second problem is that even though `this.on_draw` is invoked, the changes made to the `Context` is not displayed unless the `ScrollBar` value is near `0` or `100` (100 is the upper value of Adjustment). Why is this happening?

I did find out that if I `connect` the `value_changed` event of `ScrollBar` to a method that calls `queue_redraw` of `DrawingArea`, it would invoke `this.on_draw` and display it properly after it. But due to the second problem, I think `this.on_draw` is getting invoked too many times unnecessarily. So, what is the "proper" way of accomplishing this?

```
using Cairo;
using Gdk;
using Gtk;
using Pango;

public class Texter : Gtk.Window {
    private Gtk.DrawingArea darea;
    private Gtk.Scrollbar scroll;

    private string text = "Hello\nWorld!";

    public Texter () {
        GLib.Object (type: Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL);

        Gtk.Grid grid = new Gtk.Grid();
        this.add (grid);

        var drawing_area = new Gtk.DrawingArea ();
        drawing_area.set_size_request (200, 200);
        drawing_area.expand = true;
        drawing_area.draw.connect (this.on_draw);

        grid.attach (drawing_area, 0, 0);

        var scrollbar = new Gtk.Scrollbar (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL,
                                           new Gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 1));

        grid.attach (scrollbar, 1, 0);

        this.darea = drawing_area;
        this.scroll = scrollbar;

        this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
    }

    private bool on_draw (Gtk.Widget sender, Cairo.Context ctx) {
        ctx.set_source_rgb (0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
        ctx.paint ();

        var y_offset = this.scroll.get_value();
        stdout.printf("%f\n", y_offset);

        ctx.set_source_rgb (0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
        ctx.move_to(0, 100 - y_offset);

        var layout = Pango.cairo_create_layout(ctx);
        layout.set_font_description(Pango.FontDescription.from_string("Sans 12"));
        layout.set_auto_dir(false);
        layout.set_text(this.text, this.text.length);
        Pango.cairo_show_layout(ctx, layout);

        return false;
    }

    static int main (string[] args) {
        Gtk.init (ref args);

        var window = new Texter ();
        window.show_all ();

        Gtk.main ();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Also, please point out any (possibly unrelated) mistake if you find one in the above code.

Comment: What version of GTK+ is this? I suspect the first problem is caused by overlay scrollbars, but that depends on whether you're using a GTK+ that has overlay scrollbars.

Comment: @andlabs I compiled with `--pkg gtk+-3.0` option, and the installed gtk3 version is `3.22`. By "overlay scrollbars," if you meant the ones that expands when hovering over it, then it was not, at least visually. It "looked" like the regular old 3.0 scrollbar. http://imgur.com/a/NpCui (But it did behave as one, since even hovering over it emitted redraw events.) So how can I disable that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that you are missing is that a `draw` signal does **not** mean "redraw everything". Instead, GTK+ sets the clip region of the cairo context to the part that needs to be redrawn, so everything else you do doesn't have any effect. The cairo function `cairo_clip_extents()` will tell you what that region is. The `queue_draw_area()` method on GtkWidget will allow you to explicitly mark a certain area for drawing, instead of the entire widget.

But your approach to scrollbars is wrong anyway: you're trying to build the entire infrastructure from scratch! Consider using a GtkScrolledWindow instead. This automatically takes care of all the details of scrolling for you, and will give you the overlay scrollbars I mentioned. All you need to do is set the size of the GtkDrawingArea to the size you want it to be, and GtkScrolledWindow will do the rest. The best way to do this is to subclass GtkDrawingArea and override the `get_preferred_height()` and/or `get_preferred_width()` virtual functions (being sure to set both minimum and natural sizes to the sizes you want for that particular dimension). If you ever need to change this size later, call the `queue_resize()` method of GtkWidget. (You probably *could* get away with just using `set_size_request()`, but what I described is the preferred way of doing this.) Doing this also gives you the advantage of not having to worry about transforming your cairo coordinates; GtkScrolledWindow does this for you.

Comment: i hit that issue myself right now, and I also intended to do it all "from scratch" due to concerns about memory use: if I keep a drawing area of the size that's visible on screen, it'll presumably use less memory than a drawing area covering the whole scroll area? Or is scrolledwindow+drawingarea smart enough to allocate only what will be displayed? I want to scroll over a very large "virtual" display...